# C# Десерилизовать json

Tags: c#, json

Есть такой json

```
{
    "ChatDb": [
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "ChatId": 86,
            "Name": "Чат 90",
            "SettingName": null,
            "UserSoftId": 1
        },
        {
            "Id": 2,
            "ChatId": 86,
            "Name": "Чат 91",
            "SettingName": null,
            "UserSoftId": 1
        },
        {
            "Id": 3,
            "ChatId": 86,
            "Name": "Чат 93",
            "SettingName": null,
            "UserSoftId": 1
        },
        {
            "Id": 4,
            "ChatId": 86,
            "Name": "Чат 94",
            "SettingName": null,
            "UserSoftId": 1
        },
        {
            "Id": 5,
            "ChatId": 86,
            "Name": "Чат 95",
            "SettingName": null,
            "UserSoftId": 1
        },
        {
            "Id": 6,
            "ChatId": 14,
            "Name": "Чат 100",
            "SettingName": null,
            "UserSoftId": 1
        },
        {
            "Id": 7,
            "ChatId": 14,
            "Name": "Чат 101",
            "SettingName": null,
            "UserSoftId": 1
        },
        {
            "Id": 8,
            "ChatId": 14,
            "Name": "Чат 102",
            "SettingName": null,
            "UserSoftId": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Код

```
   async void GetChatHome()
{
    using var client = new HttpClient();
    UserSoft.Token = "Test";
    UserSoft.UserID = 1000;
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(UserSoft);
    var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var response = client.PostAsync("https://localhost:5001/GetChatHome", content).Result;
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var stt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(result);
        var chats = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, ChatDb>>(result);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"Не удалось получить чат");
    }
}
```

В строке `var stt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(result);`
ошибка Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '', line 1, position 1."

Json создаю таким кодом

```
/// <summary>
/// Получить чаты
/// </summary>
/// <param name="userSoftJson"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
[HttpPost("/GetChatHome")]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetChatHome([FromBody] UserSoft userSoftJson)
{
    var user = await db.UserSoft.Include(x => x.ChatDb).FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Token == userSoftJson.Token);
    var ChatDb = user.ChatDb.ToList();
    if (user == null)
        return BadRequest();
    Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8"; // добавляем указание на кодировку UTF-8
    return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { ChatDb }), "application/json", Encoding.UTF8); // используем метод Content для отправки JSON с указанием кодировки UTF-8
}
```

Подскажите, почему стерилизовав в одном проекте, я не могу деселиризовать json в другом проекте.

Comment: Указав `<string>`, вы заявляете, что в json записан строковый литерал, а строковый литерал должен начинаться с кавычки `"`, и десериализатор, видя вместо кавычки какой-то непонятный `{`, вполне закономерно ругается

Comment: @andreymal если я пробую так 
var chats = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ChatDb>>(result); // здесь дает ошибку Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: "Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Casis.Model.ChatDb]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
или
var chats = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ChatD>(result); 
то я тоже не могу десерилизовать.

Comment: Ну и с List аналогично: вы заявляете, что в json список начинающийся с квадратной скобки `[`, а вместо этого подсовываете какой-то непонятный `{`. А что такое ChatD мы не знаем

Comment: Внимательно посмотрите на JSON, у вас сначала идет `{...}` - объект, внутри идет `"ChatDb": [...]` - свойство `ChatDb`, которое содержит в себе коллекцию других объектов. Вот это собственно и делайте, условно `public class Root { public List<ChatDb>ChatDb {get;set;} }`, `.DeserializeObject<Root>(result);`. А вообще, зачем вы сами оборачиваете коллекцию в объект вот тут `new { ChatDb }`? Просто десериализуйте сразу `ChatDb` и все, на клиенте тогда `List<ChatDb>` сработает.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ ваш ответ помог, спасибо,  переделав строку ответа на 
 return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ChatDb), "application/json", Encoding.UTF8);
на стороне клиента
 var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var chats = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ChatDb>>(result);
я теперь получаю корректную модель без лишний заморочек

Comment: @andreymal понял, надо бы более детально изучить json как он относится к c#

Comment: @EvgeniyZ как вы в комментариях подсвечиваете строки? Которые выделены

Comment: @ИванРудаков Код десериализации сократить можете, да и сериализации тоже. У C# есть пространство имен [System.Net.Http.Json](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.httpclientjsonextensions), если подключите, то можете сразу писать такое: `var chats = client.GetFromJsonAsync<..>(..);`, без загрузки сначала строки, и так далее. Касательно подсветки, как и в вопросе вы вон подсветили `var stt = J`, одинарными кавычками.

Comment: Десереализация непонятно во что. Почему модель данных не показываете? Зачем вообще устаревший JSON.NET используете? Под Framework 4.x код пишете чтоли?

Comment: `.Result;` - ужс, используйте `await`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ 'Newtonsoft.Json' не особо и нужен получается, штатными средствами microsoft 'json' весь обрабатывается достаточно просто. Спасибо еще раз.
Но вместо 'var chats = client.GetFromJsonAsync<..>(..);' 
 ' var result = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<List<ChatDb>>();' так как у меня HttpResponceMessage, не люблю в catch обрабатывать то что можно без него обработать

Comment: @aepot на asp.net 6 пишу, **JSON.NET** привычка плохая, больше не буду использовать, в теме помогли со всеми вопросами и больше, про '.Result' и поставил чтобы код не переделывать на асинхронный, так как проверял работу с json и метод этот удалю и впишу в основной код то что опробовал

Comment: Когда пишете комментарий, под кнопкой "Добавить комментарий" есть ссылка "Справка". Нажмите на неё. / Для выделения кода используйте backtick.

Comment: JSON.NET не плохая привычка, да и не назвал бы я его устаревшим. Он хорош за счет "времени", ибо он в себя впитал много того, что нужно людям, он многое прощает, многое делает за вас, когда как System.Text.Json строго следует стандарту, из-за чего приходится много лишнего писать, много конфигов править, а если еще и JSON не очень стандартный, то вообще, караул, приходится кучу кастом. конверторов писать, чего JSON.NET проглотит без проблем. Так что, тут стоит выбирать под нужды, а не слепо следовать новинкам. В вашем случае наверно да, System.Text.Json будет достаточно, даже без настроек.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov `Верно` но порой спросить быстрее, хотя не всегда так